# Modify Urls using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, drupal-7

I am trying to build referral url in one of my drupal project
so these url will be shared by different users on site
and other users will come to site through the shared links
so if a node is accessed at

```
node/1 with path alias as content/test
```

this will shared as

```
content/test/referral/1
```

but the above shared url will result to page not found
so is there a way around that we share the url as

```
content/test/referral/1
```

but when request comes to drupal
it internally treats as

```
content/test?referral=1
```

This way it will not result to page not found.

Answer (score 0):

You need an internal rewrite from `content/test/referral/1` to `content/test?refferal=1`. Make sure that `mod_rewrite` is enabled for your Apache server, then add the following rule to your `.htaccess`.

```
RewriteRule ^content/test/referral/([0-9]+)/?$ /content/test?referral=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried putting this code on my .htccess file and tried to access page content/test/referral/1 getting page not found while content/test?referral=1 works.Yes mod_rewrite is enabled.

Comment: Is your `.htaccess` file in your www-root? I don't know much about Drupal, but does it access the php `$_GET` variable or does it do some fancy stuff with the actual url (some fancy `$_SERVER` element) that is accessed?

Comment: its in the drupal root, from drupal perspective it is supposed to be there and yes its getting picked by apache.